# CSS dropdown menu + carousel

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, drupal-7, carousel

I'm having trouble getting my dropdown menu right.

Two issues:
1. In Firefox, the dropdown appear left of the header block, and not under the correct menu-item.
2. In browsers where it appears correctly, it pops under the carousel when it has scrolled.

Problems (and code) can be seen here: http://vizit-dev.mooo.com

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I don't have much experience in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Start from:

1. `.nice-menu li { }` change `display: inline` to `inline-block;`
2. set `z-index` for `ul.nice-menu li { }` higher than
   `.views_slideshow_cycle_teaser_section_banner_carousel-block { }`

Comment: Number 1 does the trick, number 2 doesn't seem to have any effect :(